# Error in long decleration

Tags: java

```
long no=Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
long [] a=new Long[(int)no];
```

But I get error:

```
Incompatible types
found: java.lang.Long[]
requierd:long
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
long [] a=new Long[(int)no];
```

to

```
Long [] a=new Long[(int)no];
```

or

```
long [] a=new long[(int)no];
```

There's is no automatic conversion from a primitive array to the boxed version of the array or vice versa.

Comment: Thank You ..!! The Second One Worked.. :)

Comment: What is actually the difference between a `long` and a `Long`?

Comment: @ikhebgeenaccount long is a primitive. Long is a class which is the boxed version of long. It is usually more efficient to work with long whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `new Long[` by `new long[`. This is how you declare a long (array or not) in Java.

Answer (score 0):

long is not same as Long. long is primitive while Long is a class. So you should be either doing something like:

```
Long [] a=new Long[(int)no];
```

OR

```
long [] a=new long[(int)no];
```

A note: if long number is out of integer range, then your type cast will result in negative size and hence you would get NegativeArraySizeException and get into issue.